# Sum related to Binomial Coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, binomial-coefficients

Calculate:- $$\sum_{r=1}^{2023} \frac{(-1)^{r-1}r}{2024 \choose r}$$
And generalise the result if possible.

I've tried to reduce this to a telescopic sum but could not do it.

I've also made a recurrence relation:-

If S$_{n}$ = $\sum_{r=1}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^{r-1}r}{n \choose r}$, then S$_n$ = $\frac{n+1}{2n}$$S_{n-1}$ + $\frac{{(-1)}^n}{n}$, but could not go further.

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Сlarify what the summation index $i$ or $r$ should be?

Comment: $$\sum _{r=1}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^{r-1} r}{\binom{n}{r}}=\frac{1+n+(-1)^n (-1+n (2+n))}{(2+n) (3+n)}$$ where: $n=2024$.

Comment: Can you please show the derivation?

Answer (score -1):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{2023} \frac{(-1)^{r-1}r}{2024 \choose r}= \frac{(-1)^{r-1}r}{2024 \choose r}\sum_{i=1}^{2023} 1=\frac{(-1)^{r-1}r \,2023}{2024 \choose r}.$$